# WP_query post and event with Event Organiser

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to query posts and events created using the Event Organiser plugin. That plugin creates a taxonomy for categories called event-category.

I'd like to display 1 post that looks at the events and posts and displays the most recent post marked with the category => 'seminars'

I guess I'm not sure how to query posts and events.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$args = array(
'numberposts'   => -1, 
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'post_type' => array('post', 'event'), //look in post and events
'category__in' => array(28, 46), //category seminars=28 event-category seminars=46
'category__not_in' => array(1, 26, 27), //don't grab other categories
'orderby' => 'modified' //grab most recent post or event by last modified date
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question through lots of trial and error. Here's what I found. Use a tax_query with relation of OR to look at both category and event-category. Then look at the slug. Grab the most recent post.

```
// args
$args = array(
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'post_type' => array(post, event),

    'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'terms' => array('seminars'),
    'field' => 'slug',
),
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'event-category',
    'terms' => array('seminars'),
    'field' => 'slug',
),
),
);


// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```